# How to set width of drop-down button by customizing bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

```css
.selector-dropdown {
    padding-right: 60px;
}

.dropdown-menu, .selector-dropdown {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.btn-group, .btn-group-vertical {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn-group .dropdown-toggle:active, .btn-group.open .dropdown-toggle {
    outline: 0;
}

.btn-group>.btn:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}


.open>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-menu, .selector-dropdown {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 1px;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
}

li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    font-size: 24px;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #909090;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown open btn-group">
 <button id="vanaf" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" type="button" class="selector-dropdown dropdown-toggle btn btn-default">alle 
  <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
 <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="vanaf">
  <li role="presentation" class="active">
   <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"> alle </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="">
   <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"> Metalen brillen </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="">
   <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"> Kunststof brillen </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="">
   <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"> Kartonnen brillen </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Following picture show that the width of my dropdown button is not equal to width of ul.li.a class?

What i just want is my button width should be equal to drop-down content width which might be variable as shown in example image `alle` has only three character so it occupy less space but button width should be equal to the width of `Kartonnen brillen` text

is it possible to achieve ?

here is my customized `CSS` it makes button size variable size based on content selection it should be constant with max size of content

[image]

Comment: add your HTML Code with jsfiddle

Comment: Please create a [mcve] but my guess would be because you use width auto and probably inline block - that means that they will take the width of the largest thing inside them

Comment: I have updated my question. :)

Comment: in this case add style min-width: 210px; to the button tag

Comment: but what if my content is variable @Ram_UI

Comment: Also because your dropdown list is positioned absolutely - your button has no idea how wide it should be.  If your list is not dynamic, then I would just give the button group a fixed width and make everything inside it 100% width

Comment: no my dropdown list is dynamic, so i think solution would be i need to get width size of ul and give it to button, but how to do that ?

Comment: You'd need to use js for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var w = $(".dropdown-menu").width();
$(".selector-dropdown").width(w-15);
```

```css
.dropdown-menu, .selector-dropdown {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.btn-group, .btn-group-vertical {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn-group .dropdown-toggle:active, .btn-group.open .dropdown-toggle {
    outline: 0;
}

.btn-group>.btn:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}


.open>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-menu, .selector-dropdown {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 1px;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
}

li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    font-size: 24px;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #909090;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown open btn-group">
 <button id="vanaf" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" type="button" class="selector-dropdown dropdown-toggle btn btn-default">alle 
  <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
 <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="vanaf">
  <li role="presentation" class="active">
   <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"> alle </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="">
   <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"> Meta </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="">
   <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"> Kuns</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="">
   <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"> KartKartKartKartKart </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: For selector-dropdown class, I added min-width:210px.

Comment: but in case of less content ul will occupy more space

Comment: i have edited your example where i might face problem

Comment: added little script. this will useful to you. If the content is less or big in the list. It works.

Comment: thanks @Ram_UI it works but is there any way to accomplish this using CSS ?

Comment: @NavinGelot yes we can accomplish. But overriding bootstrap class is not a good way.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest thing to achieve is to make dropdown-menu become the same width as the button (not vice versa). Just specify button's width, and use the same width to dropdown's elements and wrap text inside of the menu.

```css
.btn-group,
.btn-group-vertical {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.open>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu,
.selector-dropdown {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 1px;
  width: 148px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
}

.dropdownElement {
  display: list-item;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

.dropdownElement>a {
  font-size: 24px;
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #909090;
  white-space: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown open btn-group">
  <button class="selector-dropdown dropdown-toggle btn btn-default">alle 
  <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
  <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li role="presentation" class="dropdownElement active">
      <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"> alle </a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="dropdownElement">
      <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"> Metalen brillen </a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="dropdownElement">
      <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"> Kunststof brillen </a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="dropdownElement">
      <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"> Kartonnen brillen </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I wouldn't recommend you to adjust button's width to dropdown's menu. It can mess up your layout when you think about creating a responsive web.

Ps. also I would recommend you styling classes instead of elements.

Answer (score -1):

Here we go  i have added the my css at the end of your css you can remove the unwanted css by comparing your css.

```css
.selector-dropdown {
    padding-right: 60px;
}

.dropdown-menu, .selector-dropdown {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.btn-group, .btn-group-vertical {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn-group .dropdown-toggle:active, .btn-group.open .dropdown-toggle {
    outline: 0;
}

.btn-group>.btn:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}


.open>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-menu, .selector-dropdown {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 1px;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
}

li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    font-size: 24px;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #909090;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#vanaf{position:relative;}

.open > .dropdown-menu{position:absolute; width:100%; max-width:100%;}

.dropdown-menu{min-width:auto!important;}

.dropdown-menu > li > a{white-space:normal!important;}
#vanaf {
 width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown open btn-group">
 <button id="vanaf" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" type="button" class="selector-dropdown dropdown-toggle btn btn-default">alle 
  <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
 <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="vanaf">
  <li role="presentation" class="active">
   <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"> alle </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="">
   <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"> Metalen brillen </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="">
   <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"> Kunststof brillen </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="">
   <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"> Kartonnen brillen </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you don't understand the question, width of the  dropdown-menu class should become width of dropdown button

Comment: so you want to expand the button's width according to the drop down width?